# How do I host a LightSwitch application?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

If I wanted to host a LightSwitch application on my home computer, what would I need to do?  My home computer has a Verizon FIOS connection.  What software, configuration, etc. would I need?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean a 3 tier web/silverlight LightSwitch application. This is just like any other Silverlight app - all you will need on your home computer is IIS (to host the website and services) and your data source (eg. SQL Server). Check out the "Publish application wizard."

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [How to: Deploy a LightSwitch Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852056.aspx) for details.

From the article -

> Once published, a .zip file that contains the package is placed in the directory that you specified for the publish output. Once this package has been created, a server administrator can use the MSDeploy tool to deploy the application to Internet Information Services (IIS) and SQL servers. The administrator can open inetmgr, and move to the location where the application will be deployed. The administrator can then right-click the location and select Deploy: Import Application. The result is a wizard which the administrator can run to deploy the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish your LS app as a "desktop" app, *all* you need is *an* instance of SQL Server.

This can be SQL Express, or some other flavor of SQL Server that you may happen to already have on your machine.

You could also use an instance of SQL server that's available to you on the network that you're connected to, if you wanted to do it that way.

You could even use the instance of SQL Express that LS installs for you (that MUST be there, you CAN'T uninstall it, or the debugging experience won't work any more).

You don't need anything else, there will still be three "tiers", but all three *can* be on your computer. You don't *need* IIS on your machine, a local web server will be created for you by the publish wizard.

Here's a link that'll give you the "official" steps to deploy a desktop app.

How to: Deploy a 2-tier Application - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852056.aspx

Yann